# What access does have to user manager in a queue?

Tags: user, queue

Scenario:- When you see a queue on UI, there are only 9 users. There is one button to see all user i.e View All User

When I click on it, it shows me a list of around 55 users with most of them having Reason For Membership as Manager of Queue Member. Again, here I can see a button view queue members and on click of it, it is taking us back to the page having 9 users.

I want to get the explanation why they are in the queue? what permission that extra user in the queue owes and why they are in the queue or any more information regarding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your role hierarchy and sharing settings. So let's say if you added a User in say a Role B which reports to Role A, then by virtue of Users on Role A being up in the hierarchy to Role B also gets added to the Queue.

Refer to this excerpt from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_queues.htm&type=5).

> Depending on your sharing settings, only queue members and users above them in the role hierarchy can take ownership of records in the queue.

Answer (score 2):

A user's manager, as defined by the Role Hierarchy, has all of the permissions of their subordinates when the "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" option is enabled for an object. This is explained more in [Controlling Access Using Hierarchies](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_controlling_access_using_hierarchies.htm&type=5). Basically, if your sharing model is set to "Grant Access Using Hierarchies", then managers of members of a group or queue automatically get access. You can configure this on a per-object basis in the [Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_owd_about.htm&type=5) settings. If you don't want this behavior, then you have to disable this feature for all users via the OWD settings.

Comment: And just wanted to add that you can only do this for Custom Objects.